# Wireshark USB Filtering

Tags: usb, wireshark

I'm using Wireshark to capture USB traffic so I can analyze the descriptors of a HID device.

Each time this HID device is plugged in, the OS will assign a new USB port. So I cannot use a predefined filter. To find the current USB port, I have to exclude all noisy ports. This is quite cumbersome; especially since the enumeration could be different when the system is rebooted.

Is there a simpler way to filter the device of interest if I know that the device is in a certain range? For example "1.50.*" ... "1.99.*".

Current filter:

> `(usb.src != "1.1.0") && (usb.dst != "1.1.0") && (usb.src != "1.2.0") && (usb.dst != "1.2.0") && (usb.src != "1.3.0") && (usb.dst != "1.3.0") && (usb.src != "1.3.2") && (usb.dst != "1.3.2") && (usb.src != "1.4.0") && (usb.dst != "1.4.0") && (usb.src != "1.5.0") && (usb.dst != "1.5.0") && (usb.src != "1.5.1") && (usb.dst != "1.5.1") && (usb.src != "1.6.0") && (usb.dst != "1.6.0") && (usb.src != "1.7.0") && (usb.dst != "1.7.0") && (usb.src != "1.8.0") && (usb.dst != "1.8.0") && (usb.src != "1.8.1") && (usb.dst != "1.8.1") && (usb.src != "1.9.0") && (usb.dst != "1.9.0") && (usb.src != "1.9.1") && (usb.dst != "1.9.1") && (usb.src != "1.9.2") && (usb.dst != "1.9.2") && (usb.src != "1.13.0") && (usb.dst != "1.13.0") && (usb.src != "1.14.0") && (usb.dst != "1.14.0") && (usb.src != "1.23.0") && (usb.dst != "1.23.0")`

Applied filter:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Improving over @Velvet answer.

You can use `addr` to match both `src` and `dst`, and slices to match the start of a string.

ie, this would match the handshake and the `1.9*` range

```
(usb.addr[0:4] == "1.1.") or (usb.addr[0:3] == "1.9")
```

A bit slower, but you can also use regexp for fitlering:

```
usb.addr matches "^1\.[5-9][0-9]\."
```

Answer (score 2):

I didn't realize at first that `usb.src` and `usb.dst` seem to represent regular strings. You can access the separate characters with array indices.

To filter the USB port range "1.50.*" to "1.59.*":

> `((usb.src[0] == "1") && (usb.src[1] == ".") && (usb.src[2] == "5") && (usb.src[3] != ".")) || ((usb.dst[0] == "1") && (usb.dst[1] == ".") && (usb.dst[2] == "5") && (usb.dst[3] != "."))`

If the same filter is applied to `usb.src` and `usb.dst`, you can simplify the expression using only `usb.addr`:

> `(usb.addr[0] == "1") && (usb.addr[1] == ".") && (usb.addr[2] == "5") && (usb.addr[3] != ".")`

To filter the USB port range "1.50.*" to "1.99.*", you can use `>=` and `<=` to specify the range:

> `((usb.src[0] == "1") && (usb.src[1] == ".") && (usb.src[2] >= "5") && (usb.src[2] <= "9") && (usb.src[3] != ".")) || ((usb.dst[0] == "1") && (usb.dst[1] == ".") && (usb.dst[2] >= "5") && (usb.dst[2] <= "9") && (usb.dst[3] != "."))`

Interestingly, when using `>=` and `<=`, the reduced form using `usb.addr` doesn't seem to work.

> `(usb.addr[0] == "1") && (usb.addr[1] >= ".") && (usb.addr[2] >= "5") && (usb.addr[2] <= "9") && (usb.addr[3] != ".")`

[image]

You have to replace `usb.addr` of the terms containing `>=` and `<=` with the specific `usb.src` or `usb.dst`. Why this is the case I didn't find out.

> `(usb.addr[0] == "1") && (usb.addr[1] == ".") && (((usb.src[2] >= "5") && (usb.src[2] <= "9")) || ((usb.dst[2] >= "5") && (usb.dst[2] <= "9"))) && (usb.addr[3] != ".")`

[image]

Comment: This is an awsesome idea. Slices syntax can be used to simplify expressions: ie `(usb.addr[0:3] == "1.1")`